# Symfony: paginate a filtered list

Tags: symfony1, pagination

Hi i have the following code:

```
public function executeFilter(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->add(NomenclatoreCodicePeer::LIST_CODE, $request->getParameter('list_code'), Criteria::LIKE);
    $pager = new sfPropelPager('NomenclatoreCodice', sfConfig::get('app_max_jobs_on_category'));
    $pager->setCriteria($c);
    $pager->setPage($this->getRequestParameter('page', 1));
    $pager->init();
    $this->pager = $pager;
}
```

It works fine, but when i press "next page" button it loose the filtered items and page as if filter had not been set.
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should debug the queries to see if they are correct on each page.

My first guess would be that the `list_code` parameter is not set on subsequent requests.
Is the `list_code` parameter also passed to the url for the second page? And is the `filter` action called on the second page? Or just your default `list`(?) action?

Comment: i don't pass list_code to the url for second page..tonight i will try!
instead in the url for the second page i call filterAction!